# Setting variable to floating integer value

Tags: bash, floating-point

I am new to bash scripting. I am currently performing a simple arithmetic problem that involves a floating integer. I know that bash by itself does not do arithmetic with floating integers. So I am using the `bc` calculator tool. The only issue is the syntax. I am able to get results but not in the desired way. How can I assign `$N_RESULTS` the value of the math operation?

```
//I get arithmetic error with this syntax
NUM1=128.17333
let "N_RESULTS = ($NUM1 - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l
echo $N_RESULTS
```

_

```
//I get correct results if do something like this
NUM1=128.17333
echo "($NUM1 - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l
```

Comment: Integer is a set of natural numerrs (0,1,2,3,...) and negative of them (-1,-2,-3,...).  Floating number is expressed with an integer value 0('mantissa') and 'exponent' which show place of decimal point in mantissa. The word "floating integer" is contradictional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NUM1=128.17333
N_RESULTS=$(echo "($NUM1 - 1) / 10 + 1" | bc -l)
echo $N_RESULTS
```

This is a slight variation on your 2nd syntax.  2nd line uses the $(command) syntax to assign the output of a command to a variable.

Comment: Thank you, will do so once it permits me.